# rJava installation on mac, incompatible library version?

Tags: r, rjava

i'm trying to install rJava on my mac but i get the following message, do you know what it means?

```
 Reason: Incompatible library version: rJava.so requires version 3.4.0 or later, but libR.dylib provides version 3.2.0
```

How can i resolve it in an easy way?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your R version is little bit behind. Have you tried installing most recent one?

In addition to that, take a look here to make it easier when it comes to macOS + R + Java struggle:

http://www.owsiak.org/?p=3671

Comment: thank you for your answer, taking a most recent one it works indeed